# ext:simple ComboBox binding issue

Tags: asp.net, extjs, sqldatasource, ext.net

I have the below code

```
<ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server">
</ext:ResourceManager>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AProjeConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT Id,Name FROM PD">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<ext:ComboBox ID="Departman" runat="server"
    DisplayField="Name"
    ValueField="Id"
    FieldLabel="Departman"
    EmptyText="Departman status" Flex="1">
    <Store>
        <ext:Store ID="Store2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoDataBind="true">
            <Model>
                <ext:Model ID="Model2" runat="server">
                    <Fields>
                        <ext:ModelField Name="Id" />
                        <ext:ModelField Name="Name" />
                    </Fields>
                </ext:Model>
            </Model>
            <Reader>
                <ext:ArrayReader />
            </Reader>
        </ext:Store>
    </Store>
</ext:ComboBox>
```

The result is an empty ComboBox. Does anyone know why this isn't populating the ComboBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to remove:

```
<Reader>
    <ext:ArrayReader />
</Reader>
```

An ArrayReader expects an array of arrays, i.e. it gets access to data via indexes.

A default JsonReader expects an array of objects, i.e. it gets access to data via properties' names.